# Is it possible to create a vector function through regression?

Tags: vectors, regression

If i have some points of the form(x,y) i can easily make a regression model and get a function of the form y=f(x) on geogebra. But how would i get a  vector function of the form
f(t)=[x(t),y(t)]?

Doing this by hand is probably far too advanced for a hs student, but is there any way to do this on computer on e.g. geogebra?

Im creating a simple video game for cs class and i want an object to follow a path from some points i have.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set $n$ of points $t_i$, $x_i$ and $y_i$, you can [fit a curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) to the set $(t_i,x_i)$ and another to $(t_i,y_i)$ separatelly, if you want a simple explanation.

Or you can fit both curves jointly, like what is done [here](https://meshlogic.github.io/posts/jupyter/curve-fitting/parametric-curve-fitting/). Basically you can solve the minimization problem
$$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \left[ (f_1(t_i) - x_i)^2 + (f_2(t_i) - y_i)^2\right],$$ where $$f_1(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} t^i, \quad f_2(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{p} b_{j} t^j,$$ to some $w_i>0$, for instance.

You can find some related results by searching for "(\min |Au-b|^2) " On SearchOnMath.

Comment: I am the hs student, not a teacher

Comment: Sorry for my distraction.

Comment: Have you studied matrices and linear systems?

Comment: Hello, not really. I think its too difficult for me to do. Thanks for the help though

Comment: In some cases, it is suffice to fit one curve to the set (ti,xi) and another to (ti,yi) separately. You can do this with Geogebra.

Comment: I tried, but my xi values jumped back and forth so I couldnt create a regular function with regression.